# Linux: How to Completely Remove ALL Traces of a Program?

Tags: linux, installation, uninstall, package-management, packages

Is there a way to completely remove ***ALL*** traces of a program in Linux?

I've researched a lot on this, and I've seen people talk about `apt-get remove packagename`, `apt-get purge packagename`, `apt-get remove --purge packagename`, and `apt-get autoremove`, but it sounds like all of these leave configuration files or other traces of some sort.

I want to remove ***EVERYTHING***, though. I'm talking uninstall and completely remove the program, the package, all dependencies, all configuration files, and all data files. Remove everything associated with the program, leaving the system like the program was never installed and never existed.

I'm looking to switch to Linux as my main OS (from Windows), but for me to sleep soundly at night, I *need* to know that when I uninstall something, everything associated with that thing is gone. I know it's weird. But you know, we all have our needs.

Please help me out here; I could even pick a distro based on this, if I had to.

Thanks, and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package? The `--purge` option does remove the program's configuration files.

Comment: The following command will also get rid of any leftover data from already-removed packages: `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge`

Comment: Probably no package manager will/can remove the traces in your `$HOME` though.

Comment: With obvious caveats and requirements, still you can use `tmpfs` for `$HOME`. (And maybe in combination with `overlayfs` or so.) But of course the traces do not go base on whether the software is removed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far! @pigeonburger I checked out the question you linked; it helps me understand what the commands do, but for some reason it doesn't sit well with me that anything would be left changed after uninstalling and (idealistically) removing everything. I just didn't know if there was a way to remove even the caveats mentioned in the answer to the linked question, the things not leaving the system unchanged. Does your code get rid of these things? Also, Tom Yan, what kind of traces are left in $HOME; how can one get rid of them?

Comment: This user has already asked 3 times the same question: once here and twice the same on UL SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657483/completely-removing-all-traces-of-a-program , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657465/linux-how-to-completely-remove-all-traces-of-a-program (my bad actually one of them was asked on SO and migrated to UL SE).

Answer (score 2):

In short, you're looking for something along the lines of "Fedora Silverblue", which is designed to have the base OS more-or-less immutable. As in, it doesn't *allow* you to install apps system-wide at all. You can still install apps to your user account, but only through Flatpak, and Flatpak enforces that all configuration for an app lives in exactly one place.

---

For desktop apps that were installed system-wide, the request is practically impossible. A traditional package manager can be better or worse at removing no-longer-needed dependencies (e.g. Arch's pacman is slightly better than apt); however, it will *never* touch files that the app has left in your home directory, such as settings or data stored within the app.

- It might not have *access* to every user's home directory, especially if they are encrypted. (Even today, plenty of family desktops have multiple user accounts.)
- It cannot precisely distinguish between "wanted" and "unwanted" traces. For example, the color scheme is obviously just a setting that can be purged, while documents created with the app must generally be preserved – removing LibreOffice shouldn't delete all `.doc` files on the system.

  But there are also many things in between, such as chat logs or browser bookmarks which are stored as internal "app data" yet they're also something that many users would prefer to keep. There are also apps which store *all* their data internally, such as note-taking software.

The same problem exists on Windows in the same way. Some programs on Windows give you the *illusion* of cleaning up after themselves, if you uninstall them they ask whether to delete *your* settings – but even if you answer "yes", they won't be able to do anything with other users on the same computer. (And because the app is now removed, those users can't just uninstall it again, either.)

That being said, nearly all apps store their data in the same 2–3 places:

- Your data in `~/.local/share/myapp`, settings in `~/.config/myapp`, and temporary files in `~/.cache/myapp` (all together being the Linux equivalent of Windows "AppData");
- For older apps – a hidden `~/.myapp` right in the home directory, containing a mix of everything.
- And sometimes a few settings in `dconf-editor`, roughly the GNOME Desktop Environment's equivalent of Windows Registry.

So overall it's again the same as in Windows – in order to truly get rid of all traces, first you uninstall the actual app, then you remove its directory under <del>AppData</del> ~/.config and ~/.cache, finally clean up <del>Registry</del> dconf. (GNOME's dconf has considerably less stuff than Registry – all data belonging to an app is always in one spot.)

However, a more reliable solution would be to install such apps not system-wide through 'apt' but instead using Flatpak from Flathub, which is more or less the Linux equivalent of Microsoft Store. Usually, an app installed through Flatpak is *required* to store everything in designated locations – it can't scatter files through your home directory but has to use `~/.var/myapp` and nothing else.

Additionally, Flatpak has much less granular package dependencies – an app can only depend on a single "runtime" instead of a hundred libraries.

(Ubuntu has "Snap Store" which is somewhat similar, but as far as I know it doesn't exactly have the same filesystem isolation.)

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer @user1686 ! Would using Fedora Silverblue be good as a daily driver, as in, would its sandboxed method of app installation work as well/smoothly as other methods?

Comment: Flatpak usually works smoothly on all distros that it's on, so I don't see why it wouldn't work on Silverblue.  (Assuming that the app _is_ packaged on Flathub, of course -- it doesn't use apt/rpm packages or anything like that.) That said, it's mostly limited to desktop apps. If you need various development tools, Silverblue has the "Toolbox" which works in a similar way, creating containers where regular rpm packages can be installed but the whole container can be easily deleted.

Comment: Okay, thank you!